# Are the flutter third party plugins safe?

Tags: flutter, plugins

I am new to flutter development so I am using plugins from pub.dev.. I don't know whether those third party plugins safe or not..can someone hack or access the user data or database transactions through flutter plugins / can a plugin act as a malware? Please help

Answer (score 0):

**You can see information on this Link:
[1]: [https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-make-a-flutter-app-with-high-security-880ef0aa54da#:~:text=Flutter%20provides%20a%20secure%20data,including%20passwords%20and%20PIN%20numbers](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-make-a-flutter-app-with-high-security-880ef0aa54da#:%7E:text=Flutter%20provides%20a%20secure%20data,including%20passwords%20and%20PIN%20numbers).**

Comment: Thank for the reply.my question is ,for example, can someone develop a plugin which can track the entire user interactions and data without noticing?

Answer (score 0):

I personally see couple of things before using any plugin

1. Number of likes and Popularity percentage.
2. Number of open & closed issues.
3. If the package is from flutter or dart team, you need not to check anything. Just start using it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you could do to check how genuine a pub.dev package is :

1. Visit their Github repository
2. Check the number of collaborators and the number of stars. Usually popular packages have a considerable number of stars and / or contributors.
3. Number of issues and if the issues were addressed by any of the contributors or the repo owner.
4. Usually legitimate package devs spend a considerable amount of time working on the package and making it easy for use by new users thus also adding documentation.

P.S. - Even if a pub package doesn't qualify any of the above checks, it might still be a genuine trustworthy package. If it's not too extensive and you have some time on your hands, you could quickly scour through the code to confirm if its safe to use.

> If you do find a package to be malicious, I recommend reporting it to the flutter team so such packages are removed from pub.dev and the portal becomes more safe for other users.